# fromJson throws Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, json-serialization

I'm trying to use `json_serializable:`.
my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  json_annotation: 3.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  json_serializable: 3.5.1
```

my stream from Firestore

```
static Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Object>> getOrderById(String docId) {
    return database().collection('orders').doc(docId).snapshots();
  }
```

my factory at order.dart

```
factory Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$OrderFromJson(json);
```

order.g.dart

```
Order _$OrderFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Order(
    common: json['common'] == null
        ? null
        : OrderCommon.fromJson(json['common'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    // goes like this
```

when i call this method like

```
Order doc = Order.fromJson(snapshot.data);
```

throws me `Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'`

But when i add another factory exactly same, just expecting parameter different.

order.dart

```
factory Order.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot json) {
    return Order(
      common: json['common'] == null
          ? null
          : OrderCommon.fromJson(json['common'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
// goes like this but EXACTLY same with order.g.dart OrderFromJson
```

And call with
when i call this method like

```
Order doc = Order.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data);
```

It works as expected. What's my wrong? Any comment appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We should let Flutter know that `snapshot.data` is a `Map<String, dynamic>`:

```
Order doc = Order.fromJson(snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

Comment: Already tried that but just tried now.

`Order doc = Order.fromJson(snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>);`


`════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
The relevant error-causing widget was
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object>>
lib\screens\order_detail_screen.dart:169`